# Counting unique values in column A where all values in column B match condition?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Suppose I have data, in power bi, in the following form...

| group | condition |
| --- | --- |
| A | yes |
| A | maybe |
| B | yes |
| B | yes |

**question**
Is there a way to count the distinct elements of one column, where every value in another column matches a condition?

e.g. can we create a count of distinct `group` values where every associated `[condition]` equals `yes`?

Comment: Filtering for `[condition]="yes"` will also count group `A`, which I do not want.

Comment: I ended up reworking the shape of the data to make this calculation easier in BI (exposing a view from the DB that does some of the necessary calculations, since I'm more familiar with SQL).

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Just use Distinctcount and put a filter on `condition`.  You don't even need to write a measure; you can do it with the visual designer.

[image]

Comment: wow, this is easy, straight forward and smart. never thought this way when I implemented the same. +1

Comment: This counts the groups where any `[condition]=yes`, not the groups where every `[condition]=yes`. The expected count from the above example is 1.

Answer (score 0):

It needs more than just a small brain-storming, please try this measure as your DAX Code:

```
Your_Measure = 
VAR TblSummary = ADDCOLUMNS(
    VALUES(YourTbl[group]),
    "DisCount",CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(YourTbl[group]),YourTbl[condition] = "yes"),
    "Total Count",CALCULATE(COUNT(YourTbl[group]),YourTbl[condition] = "yes")
    )
    RETURN
SUMX(
    FILTER(TblSummary,[DisCount] <> [Total Count]),[DisCount])
```

If we test it on a table visual, It returns:

[image: EFRR]